# how to import CSV in laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, package, phpexcel, laravel-7

[image: CSV report]
I want to create a CSV import feature with a CSV format like the image above. With the code I made as below, I always get the error: "Undefined offset: 1" when importing a CSV file.

**BookedVoucherDetailImport.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Model\BookedVoucher;
use App\Model\BookedVoucherDetail;
use App\Model\Voucher;
// use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStartRow;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
class BookedVoucherDetailImport implements ToCollection, WithStartRow, WithChunkReading, ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * @var BookedVoucher 
     */
    protected $bookedVoucher;

    /**
     * @param BookedVoucher $bookedVoucher
     */
    public function __construct(BookedVoucher $bookedVoucher)
    {
        $this->bookedVoucher = $bookedVoucher;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function startRow(): int
    {
        return 2;
    }
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */

    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 1000;
    }

    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        $data = BookedVoucher::latest()->first();
        
        foreach ($rows as $row) 
        {
            $item = new BookedVoucherDetail();
            $item->booked_voucher_id = $this->bookedVoucher->id;
            $item->course_code = $row[0];
            $item->voucher_code = $row[1];
            $item->prakerja_name = $row[2];

            $voucher = Voucher::where('code', $row[1])->first();

            // check the data in the voucher table
            // and set the status in the BookedVoucherDetails table

            if ($voucher && $voucher->claimed == 0 && $voucher->is_booked == 0) {
                $item->status = 'OK';
            } elseif ($voucher && $voucher->claimed == 0 && $voucher->is_booked == 1) {
                $item->status = 'Already Booked';
            } elseif ($voucher && $voucher->claimed == 1 && $voucher->is_booked == 0) {
                $item->status = 'Already Claimed';
            } elseif ($voucher && $voucher->claimed == 1 && $voucher->is_booked == 1) {
                $item->status = 'Already Booked and Claimed';
            } else {
                $item->status = 'Not Found';
            }

            $item->save();

            // check the voucher table.
            // If the data exists, then update is_booked = 1.
            if ($voucher) {
                $voucher->update(['is_booked' => 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to import a CSV file with a format like the example above in Laravel?

Comment: have you set the delimiter? https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/custom-csv-settings.html#custom-csv-settings

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: @SuperDJ thx, i've use delimiter and it work. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this question, it's solved. i've used delimiter and it work. thank you all

https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/custom-csv-settings.html

Answer (score 0):

The error because of there is no $row[1]. CSV must be separated by commas.
Try this in BookedVoucherDetailImport

```
$item = new BookedVoucherDetail();
$item->booked_voucher_id = $this->bookedVoucher->id;
$item->course_code = expolde(';',$row)[0];
$item->voucher_code = expolde(';',$row)[1];
$item->prakerja_name = expolde(';',$row)[2];

$voucher = Voucher::where('code', expolde(';',$row)[1])->first();
```

Answer (score -1):

Import export Excel or CSV from a database is a primary requisite for the admin project. In this tutorial, I will show you how to import CSV or Excel file and export CSV or Excel file utilizing maatwebsite/excel version 3 in Laravel 6 application.

laravelcode.com/post/import-and-export-excel-file-in-laravel-7